# Open file with application Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple problem. I am writing a batch script that needs to run a file with a specific application. With the unfamiliar file extension I am using, it will prompt what app to open the file with, but I want this to be automated.
My current code is just `start /wait example.idk`
Help would be much appreciated

Comment: `assoc /?` and `ftype /?`. For a sneak peek see `assoc .txt` and `ftype txtfile`

Comment: My problem is not that I need it to recognize the filetype, it's that I need the batch file to start a file with a certain application.

Comment: Recognizing the filetype and bind it to an executable makes `start /wait example.idk` work (and even double-clicking `example.idk` will start the correct application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly start the 'specific application' with the 'example.idk' as parameter. Something like: `start /wait "specific program" "PathToSpecificProgram\specific application.exe" "example.idk"`